# How to add back an option in select 2 which is removed already

Tags: jquery-select2

My select2 plugin drop down below,

```
<select class="select_drop wid_100" id="dropDownId">
    <option value="0">Select Account Manager</option>
    <option value="1">Justin</option>
    <option value="2">Issac</option>
</select>
```

Script below to remove an option while onchange.

```
$('#dropDownId').change(function() {                                                                            
      $("#dropDownId option[value='0']").remove();
     amClose();
});
```

In another function amclose(), I want to get back that option. Something like below.

```
function amClose() {
    $(".am_dd_text p i").click(function() {                                              
      $("#dropDownId option[value='0']").add();   
   });
  }
```

I know this won't work as $("#dropDownId option[value='0']").add() is not a function. Instead how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .detach() and keep item with events.

```
var items;
$('#dropDownId').change(function() {                                                                            
     items = $("#dropDownId option[value='0']").detach();
     amClose();
});

function amClose() {
    $(".am_dd_text p i").click(function() {                                              
      $("#dropDownId").append(items );   
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 function amClose() {
    $(".am_dd_text p i").click(function() {                                              
       document.getElementById('select-image').innerHTML = '<option value="0">Select Account Manager</option>' + document.getElementById('select-image').innerHTML;
    });
 }
```

This way if it is only the first option is to be added back, you can add it.